# How to Build Spark Source Code in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache-spark

I want to contribute to apache spark. I am using Eclipse Scala IDE to fetch the source code from https://github.com/apache/spark.git but I am getting lot of errors. Can anyone please tell me the steps needed to build spark source code and modify it? I am able to successfully build it using mvn command line. As per the Spark Read me guide **mvn -DskipTests clean package** runs well in command line. but after importing to eclipse error starts. Do we need to do any changes to built it in eclipse compiler. The Apache Documentation is not very clear.

Comment: Which errors? Please edit your question to include the most relevant parts of the error messages you are getting (please don’t post miles of stacktraces)

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you now help me or should I be more specific.

Comment: Sandeep, thanks, I can't actually help you, but I did remove my downvote. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I hope someone could help me.